# Angularfire2 Merge anonymous user with Facebook/Google account

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I've succeed to login an user anonymously and with Google/Facebook.

`user.service.ts` :

```
loginFacebook() {
    this.af.auth.login({
        provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
        method: AuthMethods.Popup,
    });
}
loginGoogle() {
    this.af.auth.login({
        provider: AuthProviders.Google,
        method: AuthMethods.Popup,
    });
}
loginAnonymous() {
    this.af.auth.login({
        provider: AuthProviders.Anonymous,
        method: AuthMethods.Anonymous,
    });
}
```

But the thing I'd like to do is to merge the anonymous user with the Facebook user.
 
Because what's happen now : 
Anonymous user => uuid 1 
Anonymous user (uuid 1) => log facebook/google => fb user (uuid 2) 
So I have 2 different uuid in the database for the same user.

Do you know how to do this with AngularFire2 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you login the anonymous user, whenever the user is upgrading to a facebook/google account, try to link first. Call anonymousUser.linkWithPopup(facebookProvider). That will either succeed or it will throw an error that the facebook user exists. In that case the error will contain the facebook credential. You can then signInWithCredential(error.credential) and merge the anonymous user with the facebook user manually (copying data from one to the other) and then you can delete the anonymous user.